# Left aligning a LaTex equation

Tags: latex, r-markdown

Below is an rmarkdown document with a LaTex equation. The default for these equations is centre. How do I left-align this equation? I have searched the similar answers but none of the suggestions work on this simple problem.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Llew Mills"
date: "1 May 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

\begingroup\Large
\begin{equation*}
\Delta PsuedoR^2_{\zeta_{0}} =  \frac {0.488 - 0.624}{0.488} = -0.219
\end{equation*}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Which Markdown parser are you using? LaTex is not supported by default.

Comment: I am using knitr and pandoc. Sorry @Felix Kling I'm still quite new to rmarkdown and LaTex and am not exactly sure what the markdown parser is.

Comment: This might help : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left

Comment: Thanks @scoa but I even running the code in that question did not work. I think I need to start a new question for this as it seems to be a problem with running LaTex packages using the rmarkdown pdf format.

Comment: I keep getting an error `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble`. Tried including `header-includes:
   - \usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble of the document but still the same error. Seems like everyone knows how to use packages but me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [latex solution on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left) gives an answer that we can adapt to knitr. To have all equation of the document aligned on the left, you can use classoption `fleqn` and write equation in regular pandoc latex-math style (surrounded with `$$`):

```
---
classoption: fleqn
header-includes:
- \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
---

$$\Delta PsuedoR^2_{\zeta_{0}} =  \frac {0.488 - 0.624}{0.488} = -0.219$$
```

Note that you don't have to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` because the default latex template already includes it.

Comment: Thank you @scoa that's great! When I use the form of equations bounded by the `$` sign it automatically left-aligns anyway; I was wondering how to get the form i used in my example to left-align. However I just tried the `\begingroup...\endgroup` form with your suggested entries in the preamble and it worked! I guess the question is now, once you have set everything to left-align by default in the preamble, how do you then get it to center-align for individual equations? Regardless for you definitely get my up-vote for `{classoptions}` and `-\setlength{mathindent}{0pt}`